# RTL support for LinearLayout in versions earlier 4.2 of android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, right-to-left

I have the following LinearLayout:

Which shows on LTR orientation: Image + Text + arrow

I want to reverse the order for RTL. On Android versions 4.2 works out of the box, for earlier versions it does not. I have added the paddingEnd and paddingStart following [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:%20blogspot/hsDu%20(Android%20Developers%20Blog)) Any idea? 
(I have enabled rtl support on the manifest also)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/category_list_row_padding_left_right"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/category_list_row_padding_left_right"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/category_list_row_padding_left_right"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/category_list_row_padding_left_right"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/category_list_row_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/category_list_row_padding"
    android:layoutDirection="locale">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:color="@color/category_name"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:textSize="17dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/category_label"
            android:text=""
            android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:textSize="11dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Prior to 4.2, support for RTL was not standard: some devices, especially produced for ME markets, used custom RTL, not always good. Other devices ignored RTL altogether, and application developers had to reinvent it from scratch.